# How to secure a restful webapi core

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I am working on a webapi core and have few methods within it. This is a restful web api.
I don't want a situation where people will grab my uri and start using it. I want only
authenticated users to have access to the webapi. I am new to this. I am using the webapi core.
A xamarin.forms app will be using this webapi.
I will appreciate some directions on how I can secure this.

Answer (score 2):

I think this REST Security Cheat Sheet can be useful

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/REST_Security_Cheat_Sheet

https://github.com/OWASP/CheatSheetSeries/blob/master/cheatsheets/REST_Security_Cheat_Sheet.md

Comment: did you ***secure*** any Non-public REST service  ?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you below approach

1. User DB - either Identity or custom store
2. Authorize your web api controller
3. Use JWT for generating JSON web token and validating them.
4. Provide access if only JWT validates. Excellent support in ASP.NET Core API
5. Provide Login (token generator API endpoint), pass JWT for further API calls as Authorization header

Comment: The application I am building is a very simple one and all am doing is storing salt and hashed password. Nothing complicated. I have user information stored in the database. My question is how do I achieve this?

Comment: Anyways now, .NET Core 2.0 is launch, use the latest one. I wrote for one of apps which can't be shared (official reason). I will try to write a blog today & share here. Let me know if u need anything specific

Comment: Do you know a tutorial to follow to get Items 1 to 5 done? maybe share in your blog and here.